# TransformPDFFields option not working in CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms using SOAP API

Tags: vb.net, docusignapi

I am trying to create envelop using `CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms` to make the pdf form fields editable. I am gettting `unspecified_error`. I have also tried removing the document from composite template and adding the document in the inline template envelop. In this case it creates and sends the envelop but does not make the fields editable.  See my code below

```vb
       'compositeTemplate
        Dim envInfo As New EnvelopeInformation
        With envInfo
            .AccountId = c.AccountID
            .Subject = subject
            .EmailBlurb = emailBlurb
        End With

        Dim template As New CompositeTemplate

        'recipients
        Dim recipients As New List(Of Recipient)

        For iRecip As Integer = 1 To packet.Recipients.Count
            Dim recipient As New Recipient
            Dim customfields As New List(Of String) 

            With packet.Recipients(iRecip - 1)
                recipient.Email = .Email
                recipient.SignerName = .Name
                recipient.UserName = .Name
                recipient.ID = .ID
                recipient.RoutingOrder = .RoutingOrder
                recipient.RoutingOrderSpecified = True
                recipient.RequireIDLookup = .RequireIDLookup
                recipient.RequireIDLookupSpecified = True
                recipient.AccessCode = .AccessCode 
                recipient.AddAccessCodeToEmail = False
                recipient.AddAccessCodeToEmailSpecified = True
                recipient.DefaultRecipient = .DefaultRecipient
                recipient.DefaultRecipientSpecified = .IsDefaultRecipientSpecified


                If (Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(.CaptiveInfoClientUserId)) Then
                    recipient.CaptiveInfo = New RecipientCaptiveInfo()
                    recipient.CaptiveInfo.ClientUserId = .CaptiveInfoClientUserId
                End If

                customfields.Add(String.Format("SignerRole={0}", .Role)) 
            End With

            'add customfields list to recipient customfields
            recipient.CustomFields = customfields.ToArray
            recipients.Add(recipient)
        Next


        Dim inlineTemplate As New InlineTemplate
        inlineTemplate.Sequence = 1
        inlineTemplate.Envelope = New Envelope


        inlineTemplate.Envelope.AccountId = c.AccountID


        With inlineTemplate.Envelope
            .Notification = New APIService.Notification
            Dim exp As New APIService.Expirations
            With exp
                .ExpireEnabled = _envelopeExpirationEnabled
                If _envelopeExpirationEnabled Then
                    .ExpireAfter = _envelopeExpirationDays
                    If _envelopeExpirationWarningEnabled Then
                        .ExpireWarn = _envelopeExpirationWarningDaysLeft
                    End If
                End If
            End With
            .Notification.Expirations = exp
        End With

        Dim tabs As New List(Of Tab)

        'add documents
        Dim documents As New List(Of Document)
        Dim matchBoxes As New List(Of MatchBox)
        For iDoc As Integer = 1 To packet.Forms.Count
            Dim theForm As Objects.Form = packet.Forms(iDoc - 1)
            theForm.ID = iDoc

            Dim document As New Document
            document.Name = theForm.FilePath
            document.PDFBytes = theForm.FileBytes
            document.ID = theForm.ID
            document.TransformPdfFields = True

            'add tabs - this will be based on metadata defined in the database for the attached forms
            For Each oTab As Objects.Tab In theForm.Tabs
                Dim tab As New Tab
                If Not String.IsNullOrEmpty(oTab.AnchorText) AndAlso oTab.TabType <> TabTypeCode.Custom Then
                    Dim aTab As New AnchorTab
                    aTab.AnchorTabString = oTab.AnchorText
                    tab.AnchorTabItem = aTab
                ElseIf oTab.TabType = TabTypeCode.Custom Then
                    tab.TabLabel = oTab.AnchorText
                End If
                With tab
                    .DocumentID = document.ID
                    .RecipientID = oTab.Recipient.ID
                    .Type = oTab.TabType

                    .PageNumber = oTab.PageNumber
                    .XPosition = oTab.XPosition
                    .YPosition = oTab.YPosition


                    If .Type = TabTypeCode.InitialHere Then
                        .ScaleValueSpecified = True
                        .ScaleValue = 0.53
                    End If

                End With
                tabs.Add(tab)
            Next

            documents.Add(document)

        Next

        inlineTemplate.Envelope.Recipients = recipients.ToArray
        inlineTemplate.Envelope.Tabs = tabs.ToArray

        template.InlineTemplates = New InlineTemplate() {inlineTemplate}
        template.Document = New Document
        template.Document.ID = 1
        template.Document.Name = "TemplateDoc"
        template.Document.PDFBytes = documents(0).PDFBytes
        template.Document.TransformPdfFields = True
        template.Document.FileExtension = "pdf"


        Dim _apiProxy As APIServiceSoap = CreateApiProxy(c)

        Dim envStatus As EnvelopeStatus = _apiProxy.CreateEnvelopeFromTemplatesAndForms(envInfo, New CompositeTemplate() {template}, True)
```

Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks,
Pulak

Answer (score 0):

The best way to debug such issues (which are sometimes bugs on the DocuSign server side) is to inspect your raw (XML based) SOAP request that you are sending over the wire.  If I were you I would include it here in your question as it's much easier to diagnose when we can see the request as opposed to the code that creates the request.

With that said, are setting the tab's `Locked` property to `false` so that it's editable?  You'll also need to set `CustomTabLockedSpecified` property to true for this to take affect.

Basically, in your tab definition code try something like this:

```
With tab
    .DocumentID = document.ID
    .RecipientID = oTab.Recipient.ID
    .Type = oTab.TabType

    ...

    .CustomTabLockedSpecified = True
    .CustomTabLocked = False
```

Comment: I have a pdf template where I am having a table, I want to populate the properties available in that table dynamically while calling createEnvelop.
plz suggest an appropriate way.